# Asp.net C# Dropdownlist not bind when host app on IIS but binds when run source

Tags: c#, asp.net

On page load if page is not postback
**When** I bind the Dropdownlist Its works well when i run the source code like see the link bellow 
[Click here to see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnwLa.png)

**But When** publish this project and run on localhost IIS 8.0 windows 7 then thsi dropdownlist doesn't bind like see the link bellow
 [Click here to see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkOKP.png)

related code behind is here

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack){
clss1 objOfclss1 = new clss1();
objOfclss1.fName = "hassan";
objOfclss1.lName = "siddiqui" ;
clsInDLL objcls = namespace.class1.Get_Something1st(namespace.class1.ReadSomthing(objOfclss1));
ddl.Items.Clear();
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("list item 1", "list item 1"));
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("list item 2","list item 2"));
ddl.DataBind();}
```

Comment: I have debugged the source code twice but no any bug find yet.

Comment: You need to share the code

Comment: maybe there's no data in the data source it's binding to?

Comment: Hi ADyson thanks to reply- Actually I am binding dropdown Hard Coded

Comment: I can't see why simply deploying the code would cause this. You might think this is a stupid question, but worth checking: In your 2nd screenshot, the list has no selected item, but if you open the list, is it completely empty as well? It's possible for a select to have no selected item, but still have items available to select. Could be a quirk of the browser. Another possibility is that the deployed code is not the same version as your Visual Studio code, and is missing the binding code. Thirdly, according to your code, binding will only happen when it's not a postback, so check that too.

Comment: ADyson - Yes its completely empty - and em sure its under is not postback block - 
And one more important thing i forgot to tell you is that Initially was not working expected even on running source code as well, But then i run my visual studio as administrator after then it is showing on source code.

Comment: Then you can try to set the Application Pool's identity to point to your administrator account also. Check this link if this is new for you: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @avi this is **terrible** advice. **Never** run a web application as administrator. You just create a massive security hole for no reason. Run it as an identity which has only the privileges it actually needs. Administrator can do all sorts of things that a web application never needs to do (including, for instance, deleting itself, or installing viruses and all sorts of other nonsense, if an attacker can manipulate the application into doing so). This is the kind of thing people do when they can't solve their problem properly, it's not the real solution and causes more problems than it solves

Comment: @Hassan.Siddiqui I think the administrator thing is a coincidence. There's no reason the privileges of the app should stop hard-coded values from displaying. The only way this could have an effect is if the app is crashing (perhaps because of a permissions issue) prior to executing your dropdown code, and somewhere you are catching and then suppressing the exception. Do you catch and log exceptions in your application? If yes, then please check your log. If no, then you really should do so.

Comment: @ADyson Chill mate. I was just suggesting that in order for him to try to debug the application. His default identity account might not have privileges on some files and my suggestion was done only to point him to look in a direction. Something similar happened to me a few years ago but unfortunately i do not remember any details.

Comment: @avi I think you should have clarified that was your purpose - it sounded like that was your solution to the whole problem, and that the application should be deployed like that just to get round this issue. It's not clear really how it would help with debugging though - if it simply makes the problem disappear, it hardly helps to narrow down the issue to the exact problem, since the app can then do whatever it likes. Checking for exceptions is a more targeted approach. Then if some privileges for a specific action are revealed as missing by the exception, they can be assigned as needed.

Comment: **@ADyson**  thanks, I have added try-catch to the code snippet - yes exactly there is exception prior to executing my dropdown code,*but* it doesn't throw exception when I run source code.It throws exception only in case when i publish project and run it on *iis*. I h'v added this code above for your assistance.

Comment: the exception description is  

`Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.

Source Error: 
[No relevant source lines]
`